# What should i add so that it will print the code and not the address?

Tags: java, file, filereader

This program is to read from a file. I would like to print out the code and not the address location. What should be added to my program?

```
        try {
            FileInputStream fileReader = new FileInputStream("Results.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileReader));
            ArrayList<Result> myList = new ArrayList<>();
            String line = reader.readLine();

            String strLine;
            String[] lines = line
                    .replace("[", "")
                    .replace("]", "")
                    .split(",");
            int flag=1;
            while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (flag == 1) {
                    for (String l : lines) {
                        System.out.println(l.trim());
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(strLine
                        .replace("[", "")
                        .replace("]", "")
                        .split(","));

                flag++;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Below are the output of my program. It shows that there are 2 address location that have been printed out.I would like to print the codes not the location

```
< STIA1113 | Science | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: A >
< SADN1033 | Math | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: B+ >
< BWFF1013 | Finance | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: A- >

[Ljava.lang.String;@45ff54e6

[Ljava.lang.String;@2328c243
```

Comment: You should use `Arrays.toString` for the string arrays retrieved after string `split` method -- then you'll see the contents of the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`java.util.Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) to print the elements of a one-dimensional array.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strLine.split(",")).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", ""));
```

Comment: It works but the "[" "]" and "," is still there

Comment: @ElbertJn I have updated my answer.

Comment: It removes the "[" but the "," is still there ```< 107 | Chemistry | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: A >,  < 108 | physics | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: B+ >,  < 109 |  Finance | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: A- >```. What should be added to split it?

Comment: @ElbertJn How about now?

Comment: yeah,tqq!!!. Do you mind if I ask one last thing?                                         ```< STIA1113 | Science | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: A >
< SADN1033 | Math | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: B+ >
< BWFF1013 | Finance | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: A- >```. If i want to make it like this where should i put the "\n"?

Comment: I mean to make it next line after<> just like the output shown above

Comment: Okay, appreciate your help